# Unable to open document on Android 7 with inAppBrowser plugin

Tags: android, cordova, cordova-plugins, inappbrowser

I cannot open any document with `window.open` on Android 7.0+ with `_system` target option.

My files are saved into `cordova.file.externalCacheDirectory` and if I open them via an file's exploratory they open correctly.

I don't see any specific option for Android 7 on [inappbrowser plugin page](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser). Should I add any things for Android 7 ?